# How to compile and run project with multiple classes in package?

Tags: java

I just realized I'm about to graduate and I still don't know how to handle this situation:

Say I have a java package named **mystuff.project1** and inside the package I have *Project1.java* (which has the main method) and *ThingThatDoesStuff.java* . Both are public classes, have the package declaration at the top of the file, etc. I can debug this project fine in Eclipse.

For maximum simplicity, I move the project to C:\ so the java files are located in c:\mystuff\project1

I navigate into c:\mystuff\project1 and type **javac *.java** to compile the class files

Now how the blazes do I run my application?

- java Project1 doesn't work
- java mystuff.project1.Project1 doesn't work
- java -cp . Project1 doesn't work
- java -cp . mystuff.project1.Project1 doesn't work

All of the above give me **"Error: Could not find or load main class"**

I've been searching SO and elsewhere to try to understand this problem but I'm completely baffled.

I've:

- cleared my CLASSPATH variable
- triple-checked PATH etc
- successfully tried compiling and running standalone class files that aren't in a package

I understand this is a stupid newbie question but I just can't figure it out. I realized every other time I've run into this problem I similarly couldn't find a solution and put all of the classes into a single file. I'd rather learn how to stop doing that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to change to C:\ and then enter:

```
javac mystuff\project1\*.java
java mystuff\project1\Project1
```

and this should work.
It's either that or:

```
javac mystuff/project1/*.java
java mystuff/project1/Project1
```

Comment: Hi Alvin, thanks for the quick response! That wasn't quite correct but close enough for me to find the solution.

I go to c:\ and run "javac mystuff\project1\*.java" followed by "java mystuff.project1.Project1"

How terribly confusing and unintuitive! Thank you for helping me solve this though, I don't think I've been this frustrated in years

Comment: I don't have enough "reputation" to upvote but I can mark it as the answer; perhaps you can edit it to fix the syntax on the "java" command. Thanks again!