# How to Run Packaged Java Class

Tags: java

Here is the code of my class.

```
package One;
public class T{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Printl");
    }

}
```

I compiled this class using.

```
javac T.java
```

Then i got `T.class` but I don't know how I can execute it? 
I tried this command

```
java T
```

then I'm getting this error

> Could not find or load main class T

I tried all methods but failed to run. I searched but unable to find the solution.

and some time I'm getting `T$1.class` and `T$2.class` what is the meaning of these classes?

I didn't created any Directory. I just create `T.java` class and then write the above code and trying to compile/run.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341622/how-do-i-compile-and-run-a-particular-java-file-in-a-package-from-cmd?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580473/how-to-compile-and-run-project-with-multiple-classes-in-package?rq=1

Comment: @JarrodRoberson still unable to execute. can you help me please?

Comment: Put your T.java under folder One, and then run javac One/T.java out of the folder, then you type java One.T to execute it.

Comment: @KeqiangLi So it's mean I need to create Directory(package) Myself? java will not create it automatically?

Comment: @UnKnown , you should take a look at [how to manage source and class files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html). Basically the implementation relies on the hierarchical file system and you could set the class path to some other value.

Comment: @KeqiangLi Ok really thanks. just last question can you explain what is the mean of `T$1.class` ?

Comment: @UnKnown Do you use any anonymous inner classes inside your T.java?

Comment: @KeqiangLi Yes For Runnable. Got the Point. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

`$x.class` files generally are created when you create an inner class.

The correct way to run it:

```
java One.T
```

Comment: No, still same error.

Comment: are you running it from the directory where the class exists? If not you will need to specify the path using the `-cp` argument.

Comment: Yes I'm running from the class's directory.